# How to setup mail server for using in Windows/Apache/PHP?

Tags: php, apache-http-server, email

I am trying to setup a web server with mailing capabilities (for development/testing) on localhost or Windows/Apache/PHP. How can I do that? So I can using PHP `mail()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076/need-a-lightweight-free-windows-smtp-server

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Server Fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin is a port of UNIX stuff on Windows.  It has a POSIX emulation DLL, and then most Linux tools just run normally.  It includes apache, and PHP.  You can download the installer from [Cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe).  You'd need to know some UNIXish stuff to get it working though.

You can also just download [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) itself and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php) and install for yourself.

Not sure what you want to do though, what do you mean by `mail()`?  You'd need to configure PHP to go to an outside mail server, so I'm not sure what you'd gain over going to the external SMTP server directly.  Cygwin has a mail server (exim) and there are others available (see the comment on your question).